# Swifty Atomic Closure Initialized Lazy Property

Tags: swift, multithreading, atomic, lazy-evaluation

I ran into the issue where in a multithreaded environment a lazy instance variable that's closure initialized invokes the initialization closure multiple times if there's a race condition when accessing the property. An example would be:

```
import Darwin
import Dispatch

func doSomethingIntense() {
    usleep(100000)
}

var counter: Int = 0

class Cat {
    lazy var sound: String = {
        doSomethingIntense()
        let isFive = counter == 5
        counter += 1
        print("Getting \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()).sound")
        return isFive ? "doctorate denied" : "meow"
    }()
}

let cat = Cat()
let group = DispatchGroup()
for _ in 1..<10 {
    if #available(OSX 10.10, *) {
        usleep(100);
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            group.enter()
            print("The cat says \(cat.sound)")
            group.leave()
        }
    }
}
group.wait()
```

A sample output is:

```
Getting 0x00007fd4f170f360.sound
Getting 0x00007fd4f170f360.sound
Getting 0x00007fd4f170f360.sound
Getting 0x00007fd4f170f360.sound
Getting 0x00007fd4f170f360.sound
Getting 0x00007fd4f170f360.sound
Getting 0x00007fd4f170f360.sound
Getting 0x00007fd4f170f360.sound
Getting 0x00007fd4f170f360.sound
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says doctorate denied
```

When I want the output to be

```
Getting 0x00007fd4f170f360.sound
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
The cat says meow
```

Currently my solution is having two bools, `initingSound` and `finishedInitingSound`, as well as a mutex and a condition variable. The mutex protects `initingSound` and the wait condition checks for `finishedInitingSound`:

```
import Darwin
import Dispatch

func doSomethingIntense() {
    usleep(100000)
}

var counter: Int = 0

class Cat {
    private var initingSound = false
    private var finishedInitingSound = false
    private var soundMutex = pthread_mutex_t()
    private var soundCondition = pthread_cond_t()
    lazy var sound: String = {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&self.soundMutex)
        if self.initingSound {
            while !self.finishedInitingSound {
                pthread_cond_wait(&self.soundCondition, &self.soundMutex)
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&self.soundMutex)
            return self.sound
        }
        self.initingSound = true
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&self.soundMutex)
        doSomethingIntense()
        let isFive = counter == 5
        counter += 1
        print("Getting \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()).sound")
        self.finishedInitingSound = true
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&self.soundCondition)
        return isFive ? "doctorate denied" : "meow"
    }()

    init() {
        pthread_mutex_init(&soundMutex, nil)
        pthread_cond_init(&soundCondition, nil)
    }
    deinit {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&soundMutex)
        pthread_cond_destroy(&soundCondition)
    }
}

let cat = Cat()
let group = DispatchGroup()
for _ in 1..<10 {
    if #available(OSX 10.10, *) {
        usleep(100);
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            group.enter()
            print("The cat says \(cat.sound)")
            group.leave()
        }
    }
}
group.wait()
```

This solution doesn't seem 'swifty' or in the design scheme that's put forth with GCD. It seems like dispatch_once might be of use here had it not been removed in Swift 3.

As an aside, is there discussion in swift's development for making these lazy properties atomically initialized (note, I'm just talking about when it's initialized, not making all lazy variables always atomic).

Comment: I wonder if you ever found a more 'Swifty' way to handle this? I found your post on the swift-dev mailing list but no replies there, either.

Comment: I also found this option https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Sources/Basic/LazyCache.swift